# MongoDB : '$err: name has to be a string' with $where

Tags: mongodb

I've been trying to use the $where functionality with a Mongo database but I always get the same error message each time...

**$err: name has to be a string**

It doesn't matter what type I actually use (string eval, function, etc) - I get the same message each time. I've even gone as far as to try the examples listed on their website and still have the same error message.

Other queries work fine - it is just the $where function that has this error.

*Running: Ubuntu on VirtualBox with latest MongoDB stable release*

To clarify, I'm using both the shell and drivers with the same error. I'm using examples similar to those found on the website.

(From the Mongo website)

```
db.myCollection.find( { $where: "this.a > 3" });
db.myCollection.find( "this.a > 3" );
db.myCollection.find( { $where: function() { return this.a > 3;}});
```

Comment: Is this from the shell or using a driver? Can you post your failing code?

Comment: Also FWIW we tend to be much more responsive on the mongodb-user list rather than here - so might have more luck posting there in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This can be attributed to a malformed entry in the system.js collection for the given database.  The case I've seen specifically in system.js is a record without a "string" name, like this:

{ "_id" : ObjectId( "4dee4ee586da7d1330b33d87" ), "value" : function (foo) ...

Remove that record from system.js and your *$where* functions should work again.

The LONG answer, or how to reproduce this:

Create a new db:

```
> use TempTest
```

Create a test collection:

> db.createCollection("myTestCollection")

{ "ok" : 1 }

Populate the test collection with some data:

> db.myTestCollection.save( { a : 1 } )

Query using *$where*:

> db.myTestCollection.find( { $where : "this.a == 1" } )

We get the expected response: { "_id" : ObjectId("4dee98e26fcbba3e6d0ba2c9"), "a" : 1 }

Now create the system.js collection, which stores js functions for server-side execution:

> db.createCollection("system.js")

{ "ok" : 1 }

Insert a record into system.js, without specifying a value for _id:

> db.system.js.save( { value : "foo" } )

Re-run the last query, which now results in the infamous error:

> db.myTestCollection.find( { $where : "this.a == 1" } )

error: { "$err" : "name has to be a string", "code" : 10209 }

Now remove that rogue row from system.js:

> db.system.js.remove()

Run the query again, and see it return the expected response again.

> db.myTestCollection.find( { $where : "this.a == 1" } )

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4dee98e26fcbba3e6d0ba2c9"), "a" : 1 }

Hope this helps someone - it drove me crazy today!